# Excel How to import data from SQL Server using Transact SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, t-sql, import

I want to Import SQL server data to Excel using TSQL. In Excel, I can retrive a table with SQL code perfectly. But when i write TSQL code instead of SQL it give me "Nothing to retrive".

Does Excel support TSQL code ? if so how can i import data from SQL server to excel?

i have this sample code BTW.

```
use GOPLUS;
DECLARE @kayitNo INT;
DECLARE @CardRefOfItem INT;
DECLARE @CardRefOfPrice INT;
DECLARE @urunKodu VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @urunAdi VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @fiyat1 INT;
DECLARE @fiyat2 INT;
DECLARE @fiyat3 INT;
DECLARE @numb INT;
DECLARE @kayitSayisi INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LG_001_ITEMS);
DECLARE @sayac INT = 0;

CREATE TABLE #UrunListesis( 
Sira INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
Ürün_Kodu VARCHAR(100),
Ürün_Adı VARCHAR(100),
Fiyat1 INT,
Fiyat2 INT,
Fiyat3 INT
)
set @kayitNo = (SELECT TOP 1 LOGICALREF FROM LG_001_ITEMS ORDER BY LOGICALREF ASC)

WHILE @sayac < @kayitSayisi
BEGIN

    set @urunKodu = (SELECT LG_001_ITEMS.CODE FROM LG_001_ITEMS WHERE LG_001_ITEMS.LOGICALREF = @kayitNo)
    set @urunAdi = (SELECT LG_001_ITEMS.NAME FROM LG_001_ITEMS WHERE LG_001_ITEMS.LOGICALREF = @kayitNo)

    set @CardRefOfPrice = (SELECT TOP 1 LOGICALREF FROM LG_001_PRCLIST WHERE CARDREF = @kayitNo)

    set @numb = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LG_001_PRCLIST WHERE LG_001_PRCLIST.CARDREF = @kayitNo)
    if (@numb >=1) 
    begin
        set @fiyat1 = (SELECT LG_001_PRCLIST.PRICE FROM LG_001_PRCLIST WHERE LG_001_PRCLIST.LOGICALREF = @CardRefOfPrice)
    end
    if (@numb >=2)
    begin
    set @fiyat2 = (SELECT LG_001_PRCLIST.PRICE FROM LG_001_PRCLIST WHERE LG_001_PRCLIST.LOGICALREF = @CardRefOfPrice+1)
    end
    if (@numb =3)
    begin
    set @fiyat3 = (SELECT LG_001_PRCLIST.PRICE FROM LG_001_PRCLIST WHERE LG_001_PRCLIST.LOGICALREF = @CardRefOfPrice+2)
    end

    INSERT INTO #UrunListesis VALUES(@kayitNo,@urunKodu,@urunAdi,ISNULL(@fiyat1,0),ISNULL(@fiyat2,0),ISNULL(@fiyat3,0));
    set @kayitNo = @kayitNo+1;
    set @sayac = @sayac + 1
    set @fiyat1 = 0
    set @fiyat2 = 0
    set @fiyat3 = 0
END

SELECT * FROM #UrunListesis
```

Much likely i just want return temporary table UrunListesis to Excel that is just it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved my problem. If you want to use TSQL in Excel. U should declare a Stored Procedure. Like This;

```
USE GOPLUS
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE deneme
AS
DECLARE @Urunlistesi TABLE( 
Sira int,
Ürün_Kodu VARCHAR(100),
Ürün_Adı VARCHAR(100),
Fiyat1 int,
Fiyat2 int,
Fiyat3 int
)
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @kayitNo INT;
DECLARE @CardRefOfItem INT;
DECLARE @CardRefOfPrice INT;
DECLARE @urunKodu VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @urunAdi VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @fiyat1 INT;
DECLARE @fiyat2 INT;
DECLARE @fiyat3 INT;
DECLARE @numb INT;
DECLARE @kayitSayisi INT = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LG_001_ITEMS);
DECLARE @sayac INT = 0;

set @kayitNo = (SELECT TOP 1 LOGICALREF FROM LG_001_ITEMS ORDER BY LOGICALREF ASC)

WHILE @sayac < @kayitSayisi
BEGIN

    set @urunKodu = (SELECT LG_001_ITEMS.CODE FROM LG_001_ITEMS WHERE LG_001_ITEMS.LOGICALREF = @kayitNo)
    set @urunAdi = (SELECT LG_001_ITEMS.NAME FROM LG_001_ITEMS WHERE LG_001_ITEMS.LOGICALREF = @kayitNo)

    set @CardRefOfPrice = (SELECT TOP 1 LOGICALREF FROM LG_001_PRCLIST WHERE CARDREF = @kayitNo)

    set @numb = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM LG_001_PRCLIST WHERE LG_001_PRCLIST.CARDREF = @kayitNo)
    if (@numb >=1) 
    begin
        set @fiyat1 = (SELECT LG_001_PRCLIST.PRICE FROM LG_001_PRCLIST WHERE LG_001_PRCLIST.LOGICALREF = @CardRefOfPrice)
    end
    if (@numb >=2)
    begin
    set @fiyat2 = (SELECT LG_001_PRCLIST.PRICE FROM LG_001_PRCLIST WHERE LG_001_PRCLIST.LOGICALREF = @CardRefOfPrice+1)
    end
    if (@numb =3)
    begin
    set @fiyat3 = (SELECT LG_001_PRCLIST.PRICE FROM LG_001_PRCLIST WHERE LG_001_PRCLIST.LOGICALREF = @CardRefOfPrice+2)
    end

    INSERT INTO @Urunlistesi VALUES(@kayitNo,@urunKodu,@urunAdi,ISNULL(@fiyat1,0),ISNULL(@fiyat2,0),ISNULL(@fiyat3,0));
    set @kayitNo = @kayitNo+1;
    set @sayac = @sayac + 1
    set @fiyat1 = 0
    set @fiyat2 = 0
    set @fiyat3 = 0
END
SELECT * FROM @Urunlistesi
SET NOCOUNT OFF
END
GO
```

and after that use this code for excel;

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[deneme]

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
```

Answer (score 0):

AN ALTERNATIVE WAY

You can import sql in to an xls file using xp_cmdshell thus inserting your table structure and data in this format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Columns>
<ColumnData Column1="asd" Column2="dsa" Column3="ads" />
<ColumnData Column1="asd1" Column2="dsa2" Column3="ads3" />
</Columns>
```

using something like

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'echo ^<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?^> >>C:\file.xls'
```

You can create a procedure with a tableName parameter which will format the table and data in the most upper format and return an output variable.

Comment: i appreciate answer. But this was so complex. i couldnt do it. Really thx for answer.

Answer (score 0):

in excel(2010) i use the following steps to return data in a table or pivot format:

- Open Excel  click on Data tab select "From Other Sources" select
  "From SQL Server"

input server info

on the import data screen

- select properties  go to definition tab set command type to SQL Input
  SQL query into Command text

select desired data output and click ok.

Comment: yea but when u do it with SQL temporary table u will get "no column to retrieve" error. Anyway thx for answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can run T-SQL from Excel if you make a **SQL Server connection** rather than using Microsoft Query. Choose **Data > From Other Sources > From SQL Server**.

Enter your server name and choose your database. Excel will provide you with a list of tables. **This is confusing because it makes it seem like you cannot use SQL or T-SQL, but you can**. Go ahead and choose a table. Set whatever settings you would like on the next page, then click Finish.

Once the Import Data dialog box appears, click on **Properties** and then choose the **Definition** tab. Under **Command Type**: change the selection to SQL. Then you can put whatever SQL or T-SQL you like in the **Command Text** box. You can now use T-SQL because the Connection String is SQL OLEDB rather than something more generic.

Once you finish entering the Command Text, Excel will give you an error telling you the connection will no longer be the same as the one you initially set up. Just click Yes and proceed from there.